# How to use Not Like comparison operator in Salesforce Database Query?

Tags: salesforce

Following is example of SQL database query

```
SELECT * 
FROM suppliers
WHERE supplier_name not like 'T%';
```

This query will returns the records where supplier_name does not starts with T

But how can I achieve the same functionality in salesforce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no select *, so you have to specifiy the exact fields to query, you'd then use NOT and LIKE, e.g.

```
SELECT id,name, otherFields from suppliers where NOT supplier_name like 'T%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this: SELECT 'fieldNamesNeeded' FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_name !=:'T%'